# Python object orientated not changing values in init function

Tags: python, oop, pygame

Hi I'm in the process of making a game and I've hit a stumbling block this is part of my code below:

```
class player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 10
        self.amount = 5
        self.answer = 0

     def move(self):
        self.x += self.amount
        self.y += self.amount


while True:
    player().move()
    print player().x
```

Its probably a really basic mistake but whatever the move() function does it doesn't ever seem to change value of self.x or self.y can someone poke me in the right direction please! Thanks, I realise I'm probably missing something very basic, I don't have much experience with OO

Answer (score 4):

```
player().move()    # create a player and move it
print player().x   # create another player and print its x
```

What you meant is:

```
aplayer = player()
aplayer.move()
print aplayer.x
```

PS: The common practice is to capitalize class names:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 10
        self.amount = 5
        self.answer = 0

     def move(self):
        self.x += self.amount
        self.y += self.amount


player = Player()
player.move()
print player.x
```

This way it's easy to differentiate between classes and objects.

Comment: Ok I get that, how do I rectify that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. what the other person said is that you need to set the "Player" as a variable such as George, then call George.move()

so

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 10
        self.amount = 5
        self.answer = 0

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.amount
        self.y += self.amount

While True:
    george = Player()
    george.move()
    print george.x
```

that should work. and you can change "george" to anything you want, just make sure it is consistent.